# How to get array of values from dynamic dropdown boxes using jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have populated my ajax success function data into a dynamic dropdown element now i need to get those dropdowns value in an array

My Ajax function

```
vid=[];
$.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'getvendors',
    data: JSON.stringify(),
    success: function(drp_vendors) {

        var s = $('<select id="vendor" class="vendor"/>');
        $('<option />', {
            value: 0,
            text: '--Select--'
        }).appendTo(s);

        for (var v in drp_vendors) {
            vid = drp_vendors[v].toString().split(',');
            $('<option />', {
                value: vid[0],
                text: vid[1]
            }).appendTo(s);
        }
tr.append($("<td />").html(s));
$('#table2').append(tr);

    }
});


<table id=table2></table>
```

I'm able to get dynamic checkbox values using following code

```
var valtxt = [];
         $("input[name=quantity]").each(function(i){
             valtxt[i] = $(this).val();
          // alert("ids="+valtxt[i]);

         });
```

Comment: You are not append newly create select to DOM. if select already exists you should use id selector. like `var s = $('#vendor');`

Comment: In what array? Question's unclear to me.

Comment: For Dynamic elements use [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach.